# How to wrap specific elements in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a WordPress plugin to generate shortcodes.

The end user has an option to generate testimonials. This will return for instance the following shortcode which will function as a slider (you probably know what I mean):

```
[testimonial]Content 1[/testimonial]
[testimonial]Content 2[/testimonial]
[testimonial]Content 3[/testimonial]
```

The above shortcode will output the following HTML:

```
<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 1</li>
<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 2</li>
<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 3</li>
```

Now, I could do a `WrapAll` to achieve what I want. But I would also like to allow the user to add a second slider with also 3 testimonials. I separate these with the following shortcode:

```
[spacer height="50"]
```

The above will output:

```
<div style="height:50px;" class="shortcode-spacer"></div>
```

Now I added another shortcode to display testimonials:

```
[testimonial]Content 4[/testimonial]
[testimonial]Content 5[/testimonial]
[testimonial]Content 6[/testimonial]
```

The final output in HTML would be:

```html
<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 1</li>
<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 2</li>
<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 3</li>

<div style="height:50px;" class="shortcode-spacer"></div>

<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 4</li>
<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 5</li>
<li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 6</li>
```

The problem with the `WrapAll` was that even with the spacer in between, it would still wrap both the testimonial groups in one element.

So I wrote the following function in jQuery to achieve what I wanted:

```
//Handling Testimonials Shortcodes 
function testimonial_shortcodes(){    
    var $html = '';
    var $counter = 0;
    $('.shortcode-testimonial').each(function(){              
        var $this = $(this);
        var $prev = $this.prev();
        var $next = $this.next();
        if((!$prev.hasClass('shortcode-testimonial')) && ($counter==0)){
            $counter++;
            $html += '<div class="shortcode-testimonials"><ul>';
            $html += $this[0].outerHTML;
            if(!$this.next().hasClass('shortcode-testimonial')){
                $html += '</ul></div>';
                $this.replaceWith($html);
                $html = '';
                $counter = 0;
            }else{
                $this.remove();
            }
        }else{
            if(!$next.hasClass('shortcode-testimonial')){
                $html += $this[0].outerHTML;
                $html += '</ul></div>';
                $this.replaceWith($html);
                $html = '';
                $counter = 0;
            }else{
                $html += $this[0].outerHTML;
                $this.remove();
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

This function will generate the following for me:

```html
<div class="shortcode-testimonials">
  <ul>
    <li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 1</li>
    <li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 2</li>
    <li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="height:50px;" class="shortcode-spacer"></div>

<div class="shortcode-testimonials">
  <ul>
    <li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 4</li>
    <li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 5</li>
    <li class="shortcode-testimonial">Content 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The WordPress function that handles the [testimonial] shortcode is:

```
public static function testimonial_func($atts, $content=null){
    return '<li class="shortcode-testimonial">'.do_shortcode($content).'</li>';
}
```

I still think there is a better way to do this, since I will probably execute this function more often, and also for other shortcodes that need some kind of wrapper to achieve the slide effect, or other things.

Comment: try this:
$('#id').wrap('div');

Comment: I would instead fix whatever is generating the li's to start with an opening ul and close it after.

Comment: @Jain
Then it would wrap all the 6 items inside one div, and the spacer will end up below the div.

Comment: @KevinB
That's possible but I would like to be able to handle these shortcodes "[testimonial]Content[/testimonial]" without the need to wrap them inside a "[testimonials][/testimonials]". This makes it more readable for the end user and better to edit.

Comment: My worry is that browser x will autocorrect the invalid html (the li's contained in something that isn't a ul) thus causing your code to not function as expected.

Comment: $('#id >li:first').wrap('div');

Comment: @KevinB Thats were I was worrying about to, I currently only tested this in Chrome.

Comment: @Jain This would only wrap the first matched element. I need to wrap all the list items that are in a row, into one div. In our case 3 in a row.

Comment: you could use `nextUntil("div").addBack()` after selecting the first, but it won't handle all cases (for example, if a div isn't the next element)

Comment: @KevinB That's probably the best way, but the end user may also use something else than a [spacer] to seperate the testimonials. For instance a [br] or a [hr], of course I could do something like a selection on all elements except the ones having the class `shortcode-testimonial`. Am I correct? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, but like you said, there's no telling what else could end up between them.\

Comment: @KevinB Yes, correct. I will try to adjust it. Didn't know about `nextUntil` nor the `addBack`. I will also try to check how other browsers are handling this.

Comment: hmm... you could do `nextUntil(":not(li)")`, then find the next set with `.nextAll("li").first()`

Comment: Haha you are a genius! Didn't thought about that one. Thank you, I will post an update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want, short and simple:

```
var set = $(".shortcode-testimonial:first").nextUntil(":not(.shortcode-testimonial)");
while (set.length > 0) {
    set = set.addBack().wrapAll("<ul>").parent().nextAll(".shortcode-testimonial").first().nextUntil(":not(.shortcode-testimonial)");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qG67d/4/

Get the first set, then loop till there are no more sets.

This will however have issues if the testimonials are nested within different containers.

here's a version that handles nesting:

```
$(".shortcode-testimonial").parent().each(function () {
    var set = $(this).children(".shortcode-testimonial").first().nextUntil(":not(.shortcode-testimonial)");
    while (set.length > 0) {
        set = set.addBack().wrapAll("<ul>").parent().nextAll(".shortcode-testimonial").first().nextUntil(":not(.shortcode-testimonial)");
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qG67d/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qG67d/4/ <- This is the new one with WrapAll, which I needed, thanks a lot for your help. And the shortcodes will be set in the same container in most cases.

Comment: oh, yeah doh that should be wrapAll. fixed in answer

Comment: No way, this is so cool haha, I love it! Great job :) It will be of great value for my plugin.

Comment: This is my final function, which wraps it in 2 elements, a `div` and a `ul`: http://jsfiddle.net/qG67d/8/